# How can I perform an Array Slice in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var mentions = ["@alex", "@jason", "@jessica", "@john"]
```

I want to limit my array to 3 items, so I want to splice it:

```
var slice = [String]()
if mentions.count > 3 {
    slice = mentions[0...3] //alex, jason, jessica
} else {
    slice = mentions
}
```

However, I'm getting:

> Ambiguous subscript with base type '[String]' and index type 'Range'

Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

Comment: You can just do `let slice = mentions.prefix(3)`

Comment: Thanks. But for reference, could you tell me how I would do it if I didn't want to prefix from 0?

Comment: You could do:
```swift
let index = 2;
let size = 3;
let slice = Array(mentions[index..<(min(index+size, mentions.count))])
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The problem is that `mentions[0...3]` returns an `ArraySlice<String>`, not an `Array<String>`. Therefore you could first use the [`Array(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#init_) initialiser in order to convert the slice into an array:

```
let first3Elements : [String] // An Array of up to the first 3 elements.
if mentions.count >= 3 {
    first3Elements = Array(mentions[0 ..< 3])
} else {
    first3Elements = mentions
}
```

Or if you want to use an [`ArraySlice`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/ArraySlice/) (they are useful for intermediate computations, as they present a 'view' onto the original array, but are not designed for long term storage), you could subscript `mentions` with the full range of indices in your `else`:

```
let slice : ArraySlice<String> // An ArraySlice of up to the first 3 elements
if mentions.count >= 3 {
    slice = mentions[0 ..< 3]
} else {
    slice = mentions[mentions.indices] // in Swift 4: slice = mentions[...]
}
```

Although the simplest solution by far would be just to use the [`prefix(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#func-prefix_) method, which will return an `ArraySlice` of the first n elements, or a slice of the entire array if n exceeds the array count:

```
let slice = mentions.prefix(3) // ArraySlice of up to the first 3 elements
```

Comment: The first solution you provided doesn't work. It still returns all 4 names.

Comment: @TIMEX That's what you're original code was doing, as you're indexing from 0 up to and including 3, hence 4 items – you can use the range `0..<3` if you want the first 3 (and of course change the count check). I have updated my answer showing this.

Answer (score 18):

We can do like this,

```
let arr = [10,20,30,40,50]
let slicedArray = arr[1...3]
```

if you want to convert sliced array to normal array,

```
let arrayOfInts = Array(slicedArray)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can try .prefix().
Returns a subsequence, up to the specified maximum length, containing the initial elements of the collection.
If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers.prefix(2))    // Prints "[1, 2]"
print(numbers.prefix(10))   // Prints "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

General solution:

```swift
extension Array {
   func slice(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
       (0..<(count / size + (count % size == 0 ? 0 : 1))).map{Array(self[($0 * size)..<(Swift.min($0 * size + size, count))])}
   }
}
```

Corrected for extra slice in case of array size is multiple of slice size as mentioned by
@mahbaleshwarhegde

Comment: This creates one extra slice  if  array count is equal to size.

Comment: func slice(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
       var range = count / size
       if count.isMultiple(of: size), count > 0  {
           range -= 1
       }
       return (0...range).map {
           Array(self[($0 * size)..<(Swift.min($0 * size + size, count))])
       }
   }

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde thanks for the fix, I just discovered the missbehaviour and came back to check if it was observed by others as well!

Comment: @bolonn please update  the answer. BW I captured the issue by writing unit tests.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

Can also look at dropLast() function:

```
var mentions:[String] = ["@alex", "@jason", "@jessica", "@john"]
var slice:[String] = mentions    
if mentions.count > 3 {
   slice = Array(mentions.dropLast(mentions.count - 3))
}
//print(slice) => ["@alex", "@jason", "@jessica"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
public extension Array {
    func slice(count: Int) -> [some Collection] {
        let n = self.count / count  // quotient
        let i = n * count           // index
        let r = self.count % count  // remainder
        let slices = (0..<n).map { $0 * count }.map { self[$0 ..< $0 + count] }
        return (r > 0) ? slices + [self[i..<i + r]] : slices
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also slice like this:

```
//Generic Method
func slice<T>(arrayList:[T], limit:Int) -> [T]{
    return Array(arrayList[..<limit])
}

//How to Use
let firstThreeElements = slice(arrayList: ["@alex", "@jason", "@jessica", "@john"], limit: 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array slice func extension:

```
extension Array {

    func slice(with sliceSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {

        guard self.count > 0 else { return [] }

        var range = self.count / sliceSize

        if self.count.isMultiple(of: sliceSize) {
            range -= 1
        }

        return (0...range).map { Array(self[($0 * sliceSize)..<(Swift.min(($0 + 1) * sliceSize, self.count))]) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.